# How to configure Apache to process PHPs in Alias

Tags: apache-2.2, php, httpd.conf

I've configured my Apache with an alias to another directory in the httpd.conf like this:

```
Alias <a_dir> "<full path>"
```

This works fine for regular HTML documents like `<a_dir>/home.html`, but PHP-files like `<a_dir>/script.php` are not processed on the server (i.e. servered to the browser as a regular text-file).

As far as I can tell, PHP is properly installed - in the "normal" directory the files are processed. I've tried to also include a `ScriptAlias`, but that didn't change anything.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide any error messages you're seeing in /var/log/apache2/access.log(or whatever path you're using)? I have just tried this on my ubuntu maverick box with the following:

```
Alias /a_dir/ "/home/USERNAME/phptest/index.php"
```

my index.php contains simply:

```
<?php
phpinfo()
?>
```

Let me have a look at the errors and access logs and should be able to know more

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, the file is simply served as a text file adn nothing is displayed in the browser. The access log only has the line ::1 - - [12/Apr/2011:11:04:49 +0200] "GET /smartersoftware/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 19

Comment: what does index.php look like?

Comment: Just like the one you had in your answer.

Comment: Could you share the httpd.conf or apache2.conf? I'm new here so not sure about where this would go but imagine [pastie](http://pastie.org/ ) would be best.

Comment: It's pretty much a common httpd.conf file see for yourself at http://pastie.org/1786253

Comment: you're right - it does look standard. Can you check that:

'log_errors=On
display_startup_errors=On'

This is within your php.ini

Comment: I did those changes, now I found [Tue Apr 12 13:59:59 2011] [warn] Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5' in the error_log.

Comment: Add this underneath:

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

`AddType application/x-mapp-php5 .php`

Comment: This didn't change anything .. where is x-mapp-php5 coming from? I thought that <filename>.php would already be mapped to x-httpd-php?!

Comment: glad you got sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The alias was workking fine, it seems that I needed the following lines in my config:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

With this, the php-file is properly processed. I'm not sure why php-files in another directory worked fine without it, but it looks like everything is working now.